# SpringBoot register a specific instance of a class

Tags: spring-boot

In SpringBoot I would like to register a specific instance (one which I instantiate) with the DI Container.  I have written some pseudo code below to show what I am after but I cannot seem to find the relevant documentation or if it is even possible.

Some JSON

```
{
   "host" : "0.0.0.0",
   "port" : 8000,
   "someSpecificProperty" : "fubar"
}
```

How I would like to write it...

```
Configuration configuration = new JsonConfigurationFileReader('./config.json).Read();

new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceAController.class)
        .register(Configuration.class, configuration)
        .run(args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to achieve this was to use an ApplicationContextInitializer.

```
SpringApplication application = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceAController.class)
                        .build();

Configuration configuration = new JsonConfigurationFileReader('./config.json).Read();
application.addInitializers((ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>) applicationContext ->
                        applicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerResolvableDependency(Configuration.class, configuration));

application.run(args);
```